# Change the URL breaks the routing prevent

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a requirement to prevent routing if it is first time **login user**, they have to stay in the **setting page** to **reset password** before do something else (or go to other pages), the code is 99% working now, I can change the `url/` refresh page, it works fine but only one issue. Here is code:

```
.state('accountsetting.security', {
        url: '/security/{isFirstTimeUser}',
        templateUrl: 'settings/security/security.html',
        params:      {'isFirstTimeUser': null}
    }) // this is where I define the route
// in the run block
.run(['$state','$rootScope',function($state,$rootScope) {
    // var isFirstTimeUser = false;
    //     userinforservice.getUserInformation().then(function(data){
    //            isFirstTimeUser = data.isFirstTimeUser; 
    //     });

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        if(fromState.name!=="undefined" && toState.name=='firsttimeuser'){
            $rootScope.isFirstTimeUser=true;
            $state.go('accountsetting.security',{isFirstTimeUser:true});
            event.preventDefault();
        }else if((toParams.isFirstTimeUser || fromParams.isFirstTimeUser) && toState.name !='accountsetting.security'){
            $state.go('accountsetting.security',{isFirstTimeUser:true});
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else{
            return;
        }
    });
}]);
```

The url is like: https://localhost/app/#/account/security/true
As I mentioned, I can refresh the page or change the url like:https://localhost/app/#/account  or https://localhost/app/#
they all work fine, but when I change the url like this:
https://localhost/app/ it will take me to the **home page**. I check console, in the `statechangestart`, I lost the `isFirstTimeUser`, it is `undefind`. any idea about it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: does the route change when you are redirected to home page ? and is not https://localhost/app/. just wondering about the `#`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You lose angular state when you go to the url of the root rather than the state url (i.e) #(hash) urls. The root url reloads the page wherein you lose memory of all javascript variables as they are all client side. Hence the variable is undefined.

State changes happen in a single instance of page load, the url changes give you a illusion as if a page load is happening

Answer (score 2):

The issue causing this behaviour is described by [Shintus answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38400214/4068027).

A possible solution would be to make sure the event order is correctly resolved. I assume `$stateChangeStart` is fired before `userinforservice.getUserInformation()` is resolved. Instead of calling them in parallel you could query the returned promise inside your `$stateChangeStart` instead of the variable assigned at any undefined time.

```
.run(['$state','$rootScope',function($state,$rootScope) {
    var storedUserPromise;
    storedUserPromise = userinfoservice.getUserInformation();

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        storedUserPromise.then(function(data) {
            if(data.isFirstTimeUser) {
                //do redirection logic here
            }
        })
    });
}]);
```

Storing the user promise allows you to only have the overhead of calling `userinfoservice.getUserInformation()` once. Afterwards any `.then` on the stored promise resolves instantly.

---

PS: you probably have a typo in `userinfo>r<service` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept any route loading in your route definition with [`$routeProvider.when.resolve`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider), check their status in the resolve block and redirect them or anything else you want to do.

[Tutorial Example showing the below code snippet:](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx)

`$routeProvider
    .when("/news", {
        templateUrl: "newsView.html",
        controller: "newsController",
        resolve: {
            message: function(messageService){
                return messageService.getMessage();
        }
    }
})`